# FSK Demodulation and Data Recovery

Tags: r, audio, signal-processing, modulation

I'm trying to implement a FSK demodulator in R.  The audio is some text data, and as an exercise I converted the text to raw binary (0s and 1s) to be able to check the output of the demodulator.  So far I've been able to come up with some demodulated data, but something is amiss: the length of the real data is 6720 characters, but the length of the demodulator output is 1345049, about 200 times longer.  So basically there's a whole bunch of extra 0s and 1s (e.g. instead of 0101001 or something, it looks like 00000111110000011111000000011111).

This makes sense because the duration of the audio file is 30.5 seconds, and multiplied by the sampling rate (44100), the result is 1345050.

My question is:  what's the proper way to recover data from the demodulated signal?  Some process like demod[1,200,400,600,800...]; but then do I start with the first bit or the 200th, or in between?  Or have I completely missed the target?

Comment: The search term you are looking for is symbol synchronization.

Comment: I willing to help you but I don't fully understand your problem. I assume you are using binary FSK. You say you have 6720 characters originally, how many bits per character are you defining? How many samples per frequency symbol are you setting? How does your demodulator recognize the start of the transmission? What did you implemented in the demodulator, a matched filter bank, FFT, envelope detector?

Comment: Thanks @VMMF -- I'm still trying to learn all that I need so your questions are helpful in pointing out my knowledge gaps.  I assumed 8 bits per character, but I haven't included a binary to ASCII converter yet.  I used an envelope detector and the demod.dpss function in R (multitaper package).  I'm not sure how to define the number of samples per frequency symbol or how to recognize the start of transmission, but those sound like important steps that I am missing.  I assumed I could convert the signal to binary, then translate to ASCII, but it seems like that's not working.

Comment: How many different frequencies do you want to send? A frequency for bit 0 and another for bit 1? Which is your sampling frequency (fs)? Assume fs is 8000 and you want each frequency vector to last 1 second. Then the sampling period would be 1/8000 and with that sampling period, trasmitting 1 second is equal to having a frequency vector of 1second / (1/8000) = 8000 samples. If instead you want each vector to last 0.5 s then they would have 4000 samples